# Is there a way to access posted data in beforeSave model's callback? (Partially solved)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

The fact is, I've been trying to make a password changing form.
I've used [this approaching so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868665/is-there-a-better-way-to-change-user-password-in-cakephp-using-auth). I liked it a lot, looks simple, but at the moment I'd like to change password field for the new_password posted in $this->data, at beforeSave it just occurs that posted data is not set.

```
function beforeSave(){
    if(isset($this->data['Usuario']['password_nueva'])){
        $this->data['password'] = Security::hash($this->data['Usuario']['password_nueva'], null, true);
    }
    return $this->data;
}
```

Looks like cake uses $this->set() method which unsets all the data not related to the model before calling this callback. Is there a way to keep data posted?

**I've noticed that $_Post is available, it's not that pretty, but I'll be using that...**

I though this was a good practice coding that way. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

I can't check right now, but have a look at `$this->params`. That's how I get hold of stuff for AJAX (I think).

`beforeSave` should be able to see `$this->data` - see http://book.cakephp.org/view/683/beforeSave

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, I've debuggin for that but have not succeed... :(
There's no params property on model I guess...

Comment: `$this->params` is only available through a controller and not a model.

Comment: @joeb - Yeah, I was somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work. I've checked my user model code and there are some differences. I've rewritten your code:

```
function beforeSave(){
    parent::beforeSave();
    if(isset($this->data[$this->name]['password_nueva'])){
        $this->data['password'] = Security::hash($this->data[$this->name]['password_nueva'], null, true);
    }
    return $this->data;
}
```

Comment: Modified as you figured out but nothing...
The thing is, before calling this callback cake calls $this->set() on model.php . I think this may dismiss anything that's not in __schema.