# cakephp2 user password confirmation then save new password

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I want to confirm user password then save the new password. I am able to validate username by this code but when i validate password, it doesn't work.
Is something i am missing or i am doing completely wrong. I am using cakephp2.5  Here is my code....

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`picture` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
`modified` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;
```

changepassword.ctp (view)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('role'=>'form')); ?>       
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h1>Change Password&nbsp;</h1></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('oldpassword',array('label'=>'Old Password','type'=>'password','class'=>'form-control'));
            echo $this->Form->input('password',array('value'=>'password','label'=>'New Password','class'=>'form-control'));
            echo $this->Form->input('password_confirmation',array('type'=>'password','class'=>'form-control','value'=>'password','label'=>'Confirm new Password'));
            echo "<br>";
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
        $options = array('label' => 'Submit','class' => 'btn btn-default');
        echo $this->Form->end($options);
    ?>
</div>
```

UsersController.php (controller)

```
 <?php
 App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {
public function changepswrd() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        $data=$this->request->data['User'];
        $data['id']=AuthComponent::user('id');

        if ($this->User->save($data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Password changed sucessfully'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'viewList'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error!! please try again'));
        }           
    }
}

}
?>
```

User.php (Model)

```
  <?php
 App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

 class User extends AppModel {

public $displayField = 'name';

public $validate = array(
    'password' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        ),
        'matchPasswords'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('matchPasswords'),
            'message' => 'Both password must be equal',
        ),
    ),
    'password_confirmation' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        ),
    ),
    'oldpassword' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Please Enter old password',
        ),
        'matching'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('matching'),
            'message' => 'wrong password',
        ),
    ),
);

public function matchPasswords($data){
    if($data['password']==$this->data['User']['password_confirmation']){
        return true;
    }
    $this->invalidate('password_confirmation','Both password must be equal');
    return false;
}

public function matching($data){
    $pswrd=AuthComponent::user('password');
    if($pswrd==$this->data['User']['oldpassword']){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function beforeSave($options = array()){
    if(isset($this->data['User']['password'])){
        $this->data['User']['password']=AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
    }
}   

}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Be specific and you're mush more likely to get assistance.

Comment: means it doesn't validate password field data but when i use to for validation of username it works.

Comment: All i want is value of password field in $pswrd variable of matching function in user.php

Comment: for matching username i change matching function as $pswrd=AuthComponent::user('username'); and in changepassword.ctp i just enter username in oldpassword field by this way it validate username but same process for password field it doesn't validate. I checked my code thoroughly and i am not able to retrieve password field data from database unhashed that is the problem....

Comment: You need to hash the newly entered "oldpassword" field prior to the validation and compare it to the hashed value in the database.  You can do this in the beforeValidate() callback function.

Answer (score 0):

**My Way of doing this :**

```
function oldPasswordCheck($check){  
        $user = $this->find(
            'count',
            array('conditions' => array(
                'User.id' => $this->session_id,
                'User.password' => md5($this->data['User']['old_password'])
            ))
        );
        if(!$user){
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Other help full link is

**[Click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868665/is-there-a-better-way-to-change-user-password-in-cakephp-using-auth)**

Hope this info helps you.